# sql select max date in a query

Tags: sql, inner-join, greatest-n-per-group

I have a query like this

```
SELECT DISTINCT
FND.ID_CON,
SPRT.CODE,
SPRT.NOM,
SPRT.DATE_VALUE,
COTPLACE.LIBELLE
FROM
FND,
SPRT,
CONTRACT,
COTPLACE
WHERE
FND.code=SPRT.code
and FND.cot_place=SPRT.cot_place
and FND.cot_place=COTPLACE.cot_place(+)
and FND.origine=SPRT.origine
and FND.ID_CON=CONTRACT.ID_CON
and FND.ORIGINE=CONTRACT.ORIGINE
and SPRT.code = '12345678' 
and CONTRACT.ID_CON like '%ABC123%'
```

....

this query returns two lignes with different DATE_VALUE
how to select only the line with max DATE_VALUE?
Thanks

Comment: (1) Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  (2) Learn to use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  (3) Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: hello. I am sorry but my query is more complex and long that's why i juste put a simple example. I modufy my query and edit my question

Comment: It is rude to change a question after it has been answered.  It is much better to ask another question.  Changing a question can (and in this case does) invalidate the answers, which in turn invites downvotes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `max`:

```
select nom, prenom, max(date_empl)
from your_table
where your_condition
group by nom, prenom
```

Comment: Good catch! :) In this case he/she probably need to add id in group by clause but this wasn't the question ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `order by` + `LIMIT 1`:

```
select nom, prenom, date_empl
from person, employ, enterprise
where person.id= "test"
and person.id= emploi.id
and person.enterpriseName = enterprise.name
order by date_empl DESC LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

THIS ANSWERS THE ORIGINAL VERSION OF THE QUESTION.

This assumes that you mean that you get multiple rows for the same `nom`/`prenom` combination. One typical method is:

```
select p.nom, p.prenom, max(e.date_empl)
from person p join
     employ em
     on p.id = em.id 
where p.id = 'test'
group by p.nom, p.prenom;
```

The `enterprise` table would not seem to be needed for this query.

Notes:

- *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper explicit `JOIN` syntax.
- Use table aliases that are abbreviations for table names.
- Always qualify column names (especially in a query that references more than one table).

  - Don't use tables that are not needed.

If you just want one row returned, you would use `ORDER BY` and some way of limiting the results.  The ANSI standard method is:

```
select p.nom, p.prenom, e.date_empl
from person p join
     employ em
     on p.id = em.id 
where p.id = 'test'
order by e.date_empl desc
fetch first 1 row only;
```

Comment: there's a litlle flaw but it's not your fault as the column names are named in French :  _nom_ and _prenom_ means _LastName_ and _FirstName_, thus this will lead in grouping potential homonyms together. Better to `GROUP BY p.id, p.nom, p.prenom` here